# Memoize object lazily so that first attempt to access it would load it

Tags: javascript, object, npm, lazy-evaluation, memoization

Is there some npm package for memoizing object lazily, so that the first attempt to access it would load it?

**The problem**:

```
// service

class Service {
  private readonly pathMap = {
    user: process.env.USER_PATH,
    post: process.env.POST_PATH,
    page: process.env.PAGE_PATH,
  }
  
  getPath(entityType: EntityType) {
    return this.pathMap[entityType];
  }
}

export const service = new Service();

// service.spec.ts

import { service } from './service';
import { loadEnvVars } from '@app/loadEnvVars';

describe('service', () => { 
  beforeAll(loadEnvVars);

  it('should return path', () => {
    expect(service.getPath('user')).toBe(process.env.USER_PATH);
    expect(service.getPath('post')).toBe(process.env.POST_PATH);
    expect(service.getPath('page')).toBe(process.env.PAGE_PATH);
  });
 });
```

The tests will fail because the singleton service will load before the *loadEnvVars* due to the import of the service (before the *beforeAll*), which means the env vars will be set to undefined in the service *pathMap*.

**The proposed solution**:

I know there are several ways to fix it, but IMO the best solution would be to somehow lazy load the *pathMap* object so that the first attempt to get something from it will actually init the variable's value.

Here's a function I wrote to tackle this (Typescript):

```
export function lazy<T extends (...args: any[]) => any>(factory: T): ReturnType<T> {
  let obj: ReturnType<T> | undefined;
  const proxy = new Proxy(
    {},
    {
      get(_, key) {
        if (!obj) {
          obj = factory();
        }
        return obj[key];
      }
    }
  );
  return proxy as ReturnType<T>;
}
```

Now the service will look like this instead:

```
class Service {
  private readonly pathMap = lazy(() => ({
    user: process.env.USER_PATH,
    post: process.env.POST_PATH,
    page: process.env.PAGE_PATH,
  }));
  
  getPath(entityType: EntityType) {
    return this.pathMap[entityType];
  }
}

export const service = new Service();
```

Now the tests will pass.

**Note**: In this solution *lazy* returns a read-only object. It can be changed of course.

**The question**:

Is there some NPM library out there that provides something like that already? Cause if not I think I might publish it myself.

Comment: Why not just lazily memoize the value directly in the method? https://tsplay.dev/m3Pq2W

Comment: This is just one case. But even in this case I want it to be without a switch case, so that the efficiency will be O(1)